# How to convert a list of objects containing other objects into HashMap

Tags: java-8, java-stream

hope you are doing well.

I have some list of other object which again contains two different objects. I have tried couple of ways using `Collectors.groupingBy()` but didn't get expected output. So help me to figure out solution to this.

Suppose I following three entities:

```
class FruitFlower {
    Fruit fruit;
    Flower flower;
}

class Fruit {
    String name;
}

class Flower {
    String name;
}
```

And I have a list like this

```
 List<FruitFlower> fruitFlowers = new ArrayList<>();
        fruitFlowers.addAll(
                new FruitFlower(
                        new Fruit("Apple"),
                        new Flower("Rose")
                ),
                new FruitFlower(
                        new Fruit("Banana"),
                        new Flower("Lily")
                ),
                new FruitFlower(
                        new Fruit("Apple"),
                        new Flower("Sunflower")
                ),
                new FruitFlower(
                        new Fruit("Banana"),
                        new Flower("Purple")
                ),
                new FruitFlower(
                        new Fruit("Banana"),
                        new Flower("Rose")
                )
        );
```

Now, I want to order this list by some filter such that it returns HashMap like this

```
        HashMap<Fruit,List<Flower>> hashMap=new HashMap<>();

Resultant Object:
{
     "Apple":["Rose","Sunflower"]
      "Banana":["Lily","Purple","Rose"]
}
```

Where

Expected output is a HadhMap that contains only unique values and a list of other values connected to that particular object. You can consider Objects of String for simplicity.

This is Java question and expected answer should be in Java 8 using stream API.

*Thank you in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, `groupingBy` is the right approach.

```
fruitFlowers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    i -> i.fruit,
    Collectors.mapping(i -> i.flower, Collectors.toList())
));
```

The first parameter to `groupingBy` defines how you want to group them. In this case, we want to group by fruits.

The second parameter describes what the value of the resulting map should be. In this case, we want the values to be the list of flowers.

Note that this approach *only* works if `groupingBy` can deduce that two fruits are equivalent. This requires that the `Fruit` class contains an appropriate implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`.

If the `Fruit` class cannot be extended to add those methods, one can change the first lambda to `i -> i.fruit.name`, but that would make the resulting `Map` to have `String` keys instead of `Fruit`.